# Grunt, Bower and Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, gruntjs, less, bower

My *understanding* is that Bootstrap 3 is compiled using [LESS](http://lesscss.org/). Meaning, if I want to customize Bootstrap's theming/look-and-feel, I would modify the variables in the various LESS files, and then compile my custom Bootstrap lib.

My *understanding* is that [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) is a build system for JavaScript, that does things like minification, uglification, etc.; and that it has a pluggable architecture for defining custom behaviour.

My *understanding* is that [Bower](http://bower.io/) is a dependency management tool that can run standalone (from the shell) or as a Grunt plugin.

If anything I have said so far is not true or is mislead, please begin by correcting me!

Assuming I'm more or less correct with my understanding, then my question is:

How could I use LESS, Grunt and Bower together for creating a customized Bootstrap-based app? Would I use LESS for the custom Bootstrap, then use Bower to pull that custom Boostrap into my app as a dependency, and then use Grunt to compile/minify my app's JS/CSS resources? Or am I way off track and completely off-base here?

Comment: Your understanding is correct. Except for the "then use Bower to pull that custom Bootstrap into my app" part; your custom Bootstrap wouldn't be a Bower package. Also, speaking generally, Bower doesn't really add much value; other front-end packaging tools are much more featureful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are right.

Start by downloading Bootstrap's [master.zip](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/archive/master.zip), also make sure you have installed Node.js and npm.

Than run:

1. `npm install`
2. `grunt dist` (which recompiles Boostrap, CSS and Javascript)

Now you can inspect [Bootstrap's Gruntfile](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/twbs/bootstrap/master/Gruntfile.js)
 and find out how to configure the Grunt task to build and extend Bootstrap.

Bootstrap does not use Bower for front-end package management (although you can install Bootstrap with bower too), but the Roots Wordpress theme does use Bower:

> Roots uses Bower for managing Bootstrap, jQuery, Modernizr, and
>   Respond.js.

You can install any package with `bower install --save <package-name>`

Bower uses the [.bowerrc](https://github.com/roots/roots/blob/master/.bowerrc) file to install these packages.